# How to select only numbers with specific string in between

Tags: c#, regex

I wanna write a regex to select only actual GPS coordinates (not ranges) from the input (below).

This regex returns what I want BUT including the words, I want only numbers:

```
(actual (lat|lon) (\d+(.\d{1,6})))|((\d+(.\d{1,6})) (lat|lon))
```

So I want to exclude:

```
(actual (lat|lon) | (lat|lon))
```

How do I do that?

Input:

49.212087 latitude, 16.626133 longitude

lat range: 49.000000 to  50.000000 actual lat 49.212059 lon range: 16.000000 to  17.000000 actual lon 16.626276

49.21199 latitude, 16.626446 longitude

lat range: 49.000000 to  50.000000 actual lat 49.212073 lon range: 16.000000 to  17.000000 actual lon 16.626333

Comment: Regex match consists of groups, you should be able to retrieve only numbers from these groups. If you are unable to do so, please share your code.

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: This question is confusing about the ranges...Is this a validation question? **Rewrite** this and remove  the superfluous text about ranges and concentrate on the regex pattern failure. Or is that the actual **literal** data? If so put it in a quote block or code block.

Answer (score 1):

You have too many unnecessary groups. Also, since you actually need 2 groups to match the same type of value, you may use a *named capturing group*, and grab all your required matches with a regex like

```
actual (?:lat|lon) (?<val>\d+\.\d{1,6})|(?<val>\d+\.\d{1,6}) (?:lat|lon)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=actual%20%28lat%7Clon%29%20%28%3F%3Cval%3E%5Cd%2B%5C.%5Cd%7B1%2C6%7D%29%7C%28%3F%3Cval%3E%5Cd%2B%5C.%5Cd%7B1%2C6%7D%29%20%28lat%7Clon%29&i=49.212087%20latitude%2C%2016.626133%20longitude%0D%0A%0D%0Alat%20range%3A%2049.000000%20to%2050.000000%20actual%20lat%2049.212059%20lon%20range%3A%2016.000000%20to%2017.000000%20actual%20lon%2016.626276%0D%0A%0D%0A49.21199%20latitude%2C%2016.626446%20longitude%0D%0A%0D%0Alat%20range%3A%2049.000000%20to%2050.000000%20actual%20lat%2049.212073%20lon%20range%3A%2016.000000%20to%2017.000000%20actual%20lon%2016.626333&o=n). If you use a `RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture` flag, you can use capturing groups as non-capturing ones (only the named capturing groups will keep their submatches). See the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/ZsCghm):

```
var s = "lat range: 49.000000 to 50.000000 actual lat 49.212059 lon range: 16.000000 to 17.000000 actual lon 16.626276";
var pattern = @"actual (lat|lon) (?<val>\d+\.\d{1,6})|(?<val>\d+\.\d{1,6}) (lat|lon)";
var results = Regex.Matches(s, pattern)
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(m => m.Groups["val"].Value)
        .ToList();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", results));
// => 49.212059
//    16.626276
```

If you put the `(lon|lat)` into a named capturing group, you will be able to get a dictionary as a result:

```
var pattern = @"actual (?<type>lat|lon) (?<val>\d+\.\d{1,6})|(?<val>\d+\.\d{1,6}) (?<type>lat|lon)";
var results = Regex.Matches(s, pattern)
     .Cast<Match>()
     .ToDictionary(
            m => m.Groups["type"].Value,
            m => m.Groups["val"].Value);
foreach (var kv in results)
    Console.WriteLine("'{0}': '{1}'", kv.Key, kv.Value);
// => 'lat': '49.212059'
//    'lon': '16.626276'
```

See [another C# demo](http://ideone.com/2b4JNJ).

Answer (score 0):

Here is working regexp ([link to test](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%28%3F%3C%3Dactual%5Cs%28lat%7Clon%29%5Cs%29%28%5Cd%2B%28.%5Cd%7B1%2C6%7D%29%29%29%7C%28%28%5Cd%2B%28.%5Cd%7B1%2C6%7D%29%29%28%3F%3D%5Cs%28lat%7Clon%29%29%29&i=49.212087%20latitude%2C%2016.626133%20longitude%0D%0A%0D%0Alat%20range%3A%2049.000000%20to%2050.000000%20actual%20lat%2049.212059%20lon%20range%3A%2016.000000%20to%2017.000000%20actual%20lon%2016.626276%0D%0A%0D%0A49.21199%20latitude%2C%2016.626446%20longitude%0D%0A%0D%0Alat%20range%3A%2049.000000%20to%2050.000000%20actual%20lat%2049.212073%20lon%20range%3A%2016.000000%20to%2017.000000%20actual%20lon%2016.626333)):

```
((?<=actual\s(lat|lon)\s)(\d+(.\d{1,6})))|((\d+(.\d{1,6}))(?=\s(lat|lon)))
```

You can find more information how it's working http://codeasp.net/blogs/microsoft-net/293/c-regex-extract-the-text-between-square-brackets-without-returning-the-brackets-themselves

Answer (score 0):

If I've understud your query correctly, this regex should work for you:

`(?<=(actual (lat|lon) ))(\d+(.\d{1,6}))|(?<!((lat|lon) range: ))(\d+(.\d{1,6}))(?=( (lat|lon)))`

See also my test results on [Regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%28actual%20%28lat%7Clon%29%20%29%29%28%5Cd%2B%28.%5Cd%7B1%2C6%7D%29%29%7C%28%3F%3C!%28%28lat%7Clon%29%20range%3A%20%29%29%28%5Cd%2B%28.%5Cd%7B1%2C6%7D%29%29%28%3F%3D%28%20%28lat%7Clon%29%29%29&i=49.212087%20latitude%2C%2016.626133%20longitude%0D%0A%0D%0Alat%20range%3A%2049.000000%20to%2050.000000%20actual%20lat%2049.212059%20lon%20range%3A%2016.000000%20to%2017.000000%20actual%20lon%2016.626276%0D%0A%0D%0A49.21199%20latitude%2C%2016.626446%20longitude%0D%0A%0D%0Alat%20range%3A%2049.000000%20to%2050.000000%20actual%20lat%2049.212073%20lon%20range%3A%2016.000000%20to%2017.000000%20actual%20lon%2016.626333)

You can learn more about lookback and lookaheads in this topic:
[Regex lookahead, lookbehind and atomic groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups)

Answer (score 0):

> This regex returns what I want BUT including the words, I want only numbers:

In the realm of regular expressions there is a difference between a **match** and a **capture** and basic **grouping**. You are telling it to match and *capture* thanks to the `( )` constructs.

Keep these items in mind.

- `Groups[0]` is **always** the **whole match**
- `Groups[1-N]` are individual captures when `( )` construct is specified.
- Extract your data, the numbers you mentioned) only out of **capture** groups with index value > 0. Use only `Groups[0]` when you want just the full match.

---

**`([\d.]+)\s(\D+)`**

Using this pattern on your data, you can get these two matches

```
Match #0
          [0]:  49.212087 latitude, 
  ["1"] → [1]:  49.212087
  ["2"] → [2]:  latitude, 

Match #1
          [0]:  16.626133 longitude
  ["1"] → [1]:  16.626133
  ["2"] → [2]:  longitude
```

---

**Named Captures**

If one used named captures `(?<{name here})`, you can access the info via named groups such as `mymatch.Groups["Data"].Value` or `mymatch.Groups[1].Value`.

---

**`(?<Data>[\d.]+)\s(?<What>\D+)`**

Use of this pattern has these matches and group captures, which are indexable by int, but also via the quoted strings of "Data" and "What":

```
Match #0
             [0]:  49.212087 latitude, 
  ["Data"] → [1]:  49.212087
  ["What"] → [2]:  latitude, 

Match #1
             [0]:  16.626133 longitude
  ["Data"] → [1]:  16.626133
  ["What"] → [2]:  longitude
```